# Can I add to my groups in the current (shell) process?

Tags: shell, process, group

If I add myself to a group, it applies only to newly launched processes. Actually it's more restricted than that; it seems to apply only to new logins. I'm not sure what the exact mechanism is, but that's not my question (though I'm curious about that too).

My question is this: Is it possible to update my group membership *in the current shell process*?

I suspect the answer is no.

An example (this is not a direct copy-and-paste):

```
$ groups ; groups kst
kst oldgroup1 oldgroup2
kst : kst oldgroup1 oldgroup2
$ sudo adduser kst newgroup
[sudo] password for kst:
Adding user `kst' to group `newgroup' ...
Adding user kst to group newgroup
Done.
$ groups ; groups kst
kst oldgroup1 oldgroup2
kst : kst oldgroup1 oldgroup2 newgroup
$
```

After the `adduser`, my account is a member of `newgroup`, but that membership is not reflected in the current shell process.

The obvious solution is to log out and log in again, but that's inconvenient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not possible, from outside the process itself. See [this SuperUser question](https://superuser.com/questions/56884/change-euid-of-running-process) for more discussion and an answer involving using a debugger to attach to the process and run [`setgid()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setgid) from within it.

The reason it takes a new login to accomplish getting your new group memberships is that `login` (or `sshd` or whatever) runs as root, and must set process UID and GID for your shell process, which means it is already calling `setuid` and `setgid`.